# Common keypresses in multiple project solution

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keyboard-events

I have multiple project solution and need some service keystrokes to be common for all projects of that solution.
For example if I press Ctrl+Alt+Right Shift anywhere and any time in any of included project that "something" happens actually that I can detect that keystroke immediately.

For all those projects I have common code in additional project which is included in all other projects as reference to "common.dll" so that may be right place to put this code.

Any idea on how to make that task and how that code should look like?

I am thinking on detecting those keystrokes at [PreFilter Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178600/prefiltermessage-for-multiple-keys) but I can't make that without help.
Maybe is different kind of solution better that one I think?

Comment: Are they Windows Forms projects or WPF?

Comment: Winforms project, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms raises keyboard events for you so you do not need to go as low level as handling window messages yourself. To standardise the approach across multiple forms and projects, create a common DLL project and add a reference to it in all of the other projects. Create a static class (module in VB) in the common project along the lines of the code below.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module KeyPressHandler

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Connects the <see cref="Form.KeyDown"/> event handler for a specified Windows form
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub ConnectKeyHandler(form As Form)
        AddHandler form.KeyDown, New KeyEventHandler(AddressOf KeyPressHandler.KeyDownHandler)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handles the KeyDown event for a windows form
    ''' </summary>
     Private Sub KeyDownHandler(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
       If (e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Control) AndAlso e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Alt) AndAlso e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Shift)) Then
            '' Do whatever you want here
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Then in the code-behind of each form, in the constructor, add the following line of code:

```
Common.KeyPressHandler.ConnectKeyHandler(Me)
```

(so it will end up looking like this):

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Common.KeyPressHandler.ConnectKeyHandler(Me)

   End Sub

End Class
```

The `HasFlag` method on enums was added in .NET 4, so if you are using a version before that then the logic will be a little more long winded:

```
If ((e.KeyData And Keys.Control = Keys.Control) AndAlso (e.KeyData And Keys.Alt = Keys.Alt) AndAlso (e.KeyData And Keys.Shift = Keys.Shift)) Then
```

There is still a problem with specifically detecting the right shift key as opposed to any shift key. I couldn't find a working way to differentiate it from the left shift key, although it looked like using RShift was supposed to do it. One solution might be to call the Windows API function GetKeyState (see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeystate) with the VK_RSHIFT constant. The historical reason for this is probably to do with the Left and Right shift key distinction being a later addition to Windows than undifferentiated shift keys.

Comment: Hi Stephen. These looks highly usable, I try it. Now single problem remains, how to detect press of LeftControl, Left Alt and Right shift together. Condition  If (e.KeyData = Keys.Control Or Keys.Alt Or Keys.RShiftKey) Then... passes any keypress.

Comment: Sorry, I getting error message 'HasFlag' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'. Net 2.0, Windows 7, VB 2008?

Comment: ...also see latest edit for using KeyData rather than KeyCode - I'm not having a good day with this!

Answer (score 0):

You should create one 'controller' project, which has a keyboard hook, and , maybe a fancy tray icon with animation :)

And from that 'central' project, pass the commands to the other forms...

Comment: That don't sound smart enough because I already have common project referenced to all other projects which contains low level PreFilter Messages and which should be used like 'hook'.

Comment: You comment don't sound smart enough. You allready have it, and jet you ask how to. So to come to the final conclusion, your question has nothing to do with multiple projects, you just want to know how to hook the keyboard?

Comment: Even simpler. I have hooked keyboard already for all projects under solution but I don't know how to recognize multiple key presses, for example Left Ctrl + Left Alt + Right Shift since linked premessagefilter code recognizes only one key at a time and there I havent 'modifiers', or I have?